# How to reduce XULRunner size?

Tags: xulrunner

XULRunner is LARGE, and a dependency in our platform.

It's double the size for OSX - I guess because it's built for both 32bit and 64bit.

How to best go about reducing the size of XULRunner? Something like UPX is out of the question for the largest file (XUL data). Building from source would be possible but for 3 platforms is a bit of a pain....

Any ideas?